# WCF service is not responding after app pool recycle

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, service

I have one application which is continuously checking one wcf service response, and this service is hosted in IIS.

When I run this application and service is already running in background, at that time application is getting the response from the service for n-number of time.
But when I recycle the app pool, application is not getting any response from service. At this point of time I have to restart the application, and then it works.

Please suggest me a way or any changes I should do in service to get the response from it even after recycling the app pool. I don't want to restart the application.
Or if there is any workaround that I can do in application, so that it will come to know that new session is created or app pool is recycled.

Comment: Maybe you can recreate the proxy on every invoke in your webapp, it might make it a bit slow, but its guaranteed to always get a response to the wcf app services aslong as you dont do any major changes to your wcf service

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are storing the client proxy somewhere rather than periodically re-creating it.  Once a WCF proxy has faulted, it cannot be re-used.  Re-create it.  If your WCF service is session-based rather than per-call you will run into such problems.

Comment: Yes, you are right my WCF service is session-based and it gets re-created when App pool recycle happens.
But I don't want to change these settings. Is there any way so that I can notify the user applications of this service, that, AppPool is recycled?

Comment: @AnkitSaini Unless you are using two-way communications with the service calling into the client, then probably not. If the server AppPool recycles or restarts it will invalidate all client proxies. It sounds like you are doing polling. Though not a terribly bad thing, why not poll the server every 15 seconds to a minute (depending on requirements) to get a heartbeat? If it faults, you know the server has recycled at which point you re-create your client proxy and ping it again

Comment: @AnkitSaini You could expose a WCF service in the client that the server can call (callback) to say "hi! I'm running again". That might work nicer